# WPF Datagrid binding and column display

Tags: c#, wpf

I have datatable as Item source for DataGrid, this datatable has lots of columns. Is it possible to display few columns instead all of them without creating a new table?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is. Just mark `AutoGenerateColumns=False` and manually define your columns. You can use normal text-bound columns, checkbox columns, custom XAML template columns and more, as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Simple Value"
                      Binding="{Binding SimpleValue}" Width="*" />
     <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Complex Value">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding ComplexValue}"/>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding ComplexValue2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can handle [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx) event and set [e.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridautogeneratingcolumneventargs.cancel.aspx) = true for columns that you don't want to be shown. This way you don't have to manually define columns that you want to show.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Yes very much. If your Table structure and Column Name remains constant then in Datagrid XAML set `AutoGenerateColums = False` and manually create all columns.

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="mydg" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
  <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 0" Binding="{Binding FirstColumnName}" />
  <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding="{Binding SecondColumnName}" />
 </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

and then in codebehind simple provide Source like

```
mydg.ItemSource = Data.DefaultView;
```

Now when your DataTable contains column `FirstColumnName` and `SecondColumnName` they will be databound to your Datagrid.

Comment: why there is a `dg:` prefix ..., is it a must-have?