# Changing the display method for data types in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

I'm populating a DataTable via a SQL query, then in turn handing that DataTable to a WPF DataGrid:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
myDataTable.Load(reader);
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.AsDataView();
```

Some of the data types returned from the SQL query are being displayed differently, e.g. bit columns become checkboxes and varbinary columns simply say "Byte[] Array".

How can I control the appearance of various data types in a DataGrid?

Comment: There's heaps of duplicate posts asking the exact same thing, eg http://stackoverflow.com/q/10535110/495455 you define how the data types are rendered for each column using XAML...

Comment: Thanks; I had the wrong search keywords.  I was looking for stuff relating more to XAML and formatters than binding (thought that was more data flow).