# WPF DataGrids and ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui

All I really have to go on is the Compelling Example on reactiveui.net. It used a ListBox, but I want the table look and header row that the DataGrid provides. This is what I came up with

**ChapterView.xaml** this is what I had when using `ListBox` because that's what the example used. I don't know what to put in here for the `DataGrid`.

```xml
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="AudioBookMaster.ChapterView"
                          x:TypeArguments="ABM:ChapterViewModel"
                          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                          xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
                          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                          xmlns:ABM="clr-namespace:AudioBookMaster"
                          mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Border BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black">
        <Grid Height="20"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="UI_ChapterIndex"
                     Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox x:Name="UI_ChapterTitle"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBox x:Name="UI_ChapterStart"
                     Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

**ChapterView.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class ChapterView : ReactiveUserControl<ChapterViewModel>
{
    public ChapterView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d => {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Title, v => v.UI_ChapterTitle.Text).DisposeWith(d);
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.StartTime, v => v.UI_ChapterStart.Text).DisposeWith(d);
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Index, v => v.UI_ChapterIndex.Text).DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }
}
```

**ChapterViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class ChapterViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    //TODO ChapterViewModel: Add chapter number
    //TODO ChapterViewModel: Add type (none, chapter, part, book, Section?)

    [Reactive]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ChapterViewModel (Chapter chapter)
    {
        Index = chapter.Id;
        Title = chapter.Title;
        StartTime = chapter.StartTime;
    }
}
```

The chapter class actually has a lot more properties needed for background stuff, but the three above are the only ones I need to show to the user.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="AudioBookMaster.MainWindow"
                           x:TypeArguments="local:MainWindowViewModel"
                           xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
                           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AudioBookMaster"
                           mc:Ignorable="d"
                           Title="AudioBook Master"
                           Height="840"
                           Width="800"
                           ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
...
    <DataGrid x:Name="UI_ChaptersListBox" 
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                CanUserSortColumns="False">
    </DataGrid>
...
</reactiveui:ReactiveWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Chapters, v => v.UI_ChaptersListBox.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViwModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IEnumerable<ChapterViewModel>> _chapters;
    public IEnumerable<ChapterViewModel> Chapters => _chapters.Value;

    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        GetChaptersFromAudio = ReactiveCommand
            .CreateFromTask<string, IEnumerable<ChapterViewModel>>(p => GetChaptersFromAudioImpl(p));
        GetChaptersFromAudio.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex =>
        {
            this.Log().Error("GetChaptersFromAudio command failed to execute.", ex);
        });
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AudioFilePath)
            .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
            .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.GetChaptersFromAudio);
        _chapters = GetChaptersFromAudio
            .WhereNotNull()
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(Chapters), scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }
    private static async Task<IEnumerable<ChapterViewModel>> GetChaptersFromAudioImpl (string path)
    {
        var chapters = await FFmpeg.GetChaptersAsync(path);
        return chapters.Select(c => new ChapterViewModel(c));
    }
}
```

Sorry if I added too much code, but I always get complaints that I didn't include enough.
Anyway, this all works, but I don't get the grid view I want. This is what I get

[image]

I get the three columns I want, but I also get the other ones that I don't want. I don't know how to make them go away. Am I just going about this all wrong? or is there something I can put in `ChapterView.xaml` to make this work better. I'm starting to get a handle on the basic RxUI stuff and the basic WPF stuff, but am still a novice at this, and trying to learn both at once is no easy task.

So, to boil this all down to a single-statement question; how do I only show the columns I want and in the order I want them to be in?

Comment: Hi, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535187/13448212) it seems to be what you are looking for

Comment: @Ostas That answer shows how to do it with XAML binding, which I can already do. I'm trying to do it with RxUI binding.

Comment: Well if you really want to use a RxUI binding, you could place a UserControl in the celletemplate of the Columns and create the RxUI binding from the UserControl. The only purpose would be for training though as in this case, a normal Binding is much simpler.