# Can I create a DataGrid of an object containing a List<KeyValuePair> in horizontal view?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a list of items which I want to present in a datagrid. But each item contains a list of KeyValuePairs which I want to view horizontally. Is there any way?

The object I want to present:

```
 public class ItemModel
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> DetailsList { get; set; }
    }
```

My xaml looks like this, but it returns a datagrid with Key and Value as columns instead of Key1, Key2, Key3 etc as columns:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PurchaseOrder" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="PurchaseOrder_CellEditEnding">               
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Path=Model}" />
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" CellEditEnding="Models_CellEditEnding">
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: because it's a list of keyvaluepair you can't use the autogenerated columns , you should add columns manually and define the binding

Comment: FYI - I don't think that datagrid within a data grid is a good idea

Comment: How to add the columns? I tried using dynamic object but I couldn't make the binding work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535110/wpf-datagrid-binding-and-column-display

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue I am facing. The set of columns is not fixed and thus I cannot define them in the xaml as shown.

Comment: the auto generated columns are based on the (T in List<T>) class properties so if you want auto generated columns you need to replace the keyvaluepair with your own class that will reflect the items or convert the items to you own class in the {Binding DetailsList}

Comment: another thing, if you don't need the key you can bind to the value (with converter)

Comment: can you please please post an example? I am stuck on this. How to get them horizontally and how to make the binding work even with a non KeyValuePair list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple example how you bind to a keyvaluepair + horizontal view

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="PurchaseOrder" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="PurchaseOrder_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Path=Model}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Many thanks! Can the Keys appear just once as column names? All items have the same keys and the values are a list of checkboxes.

Comment: you can remove the key in the stackpanel and add the first item key outside the itemscontrol , but this is as far as I go with this topic :)